# Vue Component prop in vuetify component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am not able to pass data to my custom component, my component uses vuetify, currently I dont get any message:

MY component:

```
<template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
      <v-card>
        <v-img
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/desert.jpg"
          aspect-ratio="2.75"
        ></v-img>

        <v-card-title primary-title>
          <div>
            <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{ tenantName }}</h3>
            <div>{{ tenantDescription }}</div>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        // ...
      }
    },

    props: ['tenantImage', 'tenantName', 'tenantDescription']
  }
</script>
```

And this is how I call in my view:

```
                    <tenant-card
                        imgSrc="https://fuckoffgoogle.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-logo_midres-1.png"
                        :tenantName="my Name is"
                        :tenantDescription="this is a description"
                    ></tenant-card>
```

The component is registered I see it on my view just without any data.

I get this outside in the page source 
`<div class="layout" tenantimage="https://fuckoffgoogle.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-logo_midres-1.png" tenantname="my Name is" tenantdescription="this is a description">
...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of your properties are wrong:

```
<tenant-card
   tenant-image="'https://fuckoffgoogle.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/cropped-logo_midres-1.png'"
   :tenant-name="'my Name is'"
   :tenant-description="'this is a description'">
</tenant-card>
```

HTML attribute names are case-insensitive. Any uppercase character will be interpreted as lowercase. So camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased equivalents.

Edit:
And as already mentioned by @Sergeon you have to add the extra `''` to pass an string as a property value

Comment: Thanks this worked, any idea why it has to be in Kebab case I thought it udnerstands both

Comment: HTML is case insensitive, so `:tenantName='WhatEver'` gets parsed as `:tenantname='WhatEver'`. But your prop is declared in javascript, which is case sensitive. To refer to this prop you have to use `:tenant-name='WhatEver'`